# @EmbeddedKafka trying to register AppInfo mbean multiple times?

Tags: spring, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I have multiple integration tests using @EmbeddedKafka, and after moving to newer springboot version 2.1.8.RELEASE, the logs fills with these stacktraces. Any idea what could cause that?

```
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: kafka.server:type=app-info,id=0
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser.registerAppInfo(AppInfoParser.java:62)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:321)
    at kafka.utils.TestUtils$.createServer(TestUtils.scala:132)
    at kafka.utils.TestUtils.createServer(TestUtils.scala)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:405)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're tests are using a Spring Test Context (`@RunWith(SpringRunner.class), @SpringJUnitConfig, @SpringBootTest` etc) then the embedded kafka is stored in the application context.

Add `@DirtiesContext` to each test class so that the instance is disposed of properly.

Comment: I'm using "@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)". And this relates to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58187190/what-is-the-proper-way-of-doing-dirtiesconfig-when-used-embeddedkafka/58187444#58187444 
  I cannot use @DirtiesContext on class level, since that produces "unreachable node 0" issues and "thread/memory leak" issue. It solves the issue of duplicate mbean, but it cannot used (7x running time, insane logs.)

Comment: Using EmbeddedKafkaRule instead of @DirtiesContext as recommended does not produce "unreachable node 0" issues and "thread/memory leak", however does not have any effect on duplicate mbean registration (InstanceAlreadyExistsException).

Comment: The `@DirtiesContext` should be `AFTER_CLASS`. The problem with `@ClassRule` makes no sense since JUnit shuts it down before the next test starts. It's not clear why you are seeing a thread leakage issue since you are running tests, not a web app. Please provide a small sample project that exhibits these behaviors so someone can take a look to see what's going on. We have many test cases in the framework and don't see these problems.

Comment: I probably don't follow. `@DirtiesContext` is by default AFTER_CLASS. Thus having `@DirtiesContext` is after_class. It makes no sense to me as well, as the context is shutdown after each file, but it kills `@EmbeddedKafka`. When used `@EmbeddedKafkaRule` we can use `@DirtiesContext`. I can try to create trivial example, but trivial examples work and typically have very little in common with non-trivial ones. Is there any other way how to debug it?

Comment: Debugger with breakpoints in `AppInfoParser.registerAppInfo()` and `AppInfoParser.unregisterAppInfo()`, as well as in `EmbeddedKafkaBroker.destroy()` ?

Comment: Oh - does your app/test use an `AdminClient` or producers/consumers without closing them? (That's where the unregister is done).

Comment: That can be the issue,we're not closing anything.However I really do not see how can I do that.We're creating ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer,ConsumerFactory in `@Configuration` method annotated by `@Bean`,without any destroyMethod parameer or `@predestroy`.And on those instances I cannot see any `close` or `destroy` method.Same for messageListener class.What I was able to find on the otherhand is your answer in some stackoverflow question,saying,that closing is not necessary:"You dont need to stop() the container from a destroy() method;the context will stop the consumer when it is closed"

Comment: putting destroy method as:
`@Bean(destroyMethod = "stop") public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer...` did not help, and that is the sole place which I was able to find as a candidate for "closing" consumer.

Comment: And when debugging I can see new registration for every `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer` but deregistration only when closing `org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient`. OK,so stepping a little bit further.I can see org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.ListenerConsumer#run being hit, and reading data in while loop:"while (isRunning()) {". And this.consumer.close() is after this while. So it seems,that my problem is, that whole "thing" somehow dies before KafkaMessageListenerContainer has chance stepping out from this while loop and call close

Comment: Right; with "active" components like listener containers, we recommend using `@DirtiesContext` at the class level so that when the test ends, the context is closed and these active components are stopped.

Comment: I'll try to strip our project to minimum failing demo so that I can show you. But so far I cannot undestand what's wrong. Close on KafkaConsumer should be called (IIUC), but it's not. Why?? @DirtiesContext produces insane problems (as said above) and EmbeddedKafkaRule does not avoid multiple registration problem. So far the only "solution" to this seems to be logback filtering.

Comment: I am not at a computer so I can"t paste a link but the reference manual shows a technique for using one broker for the complete test suite. I don't know if that will help you.